# what does "typedef __u16 __bitwise __le16;" mean in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

what does `typedef __u16 __bitwise __le16;` mean in Linux kernel?

actually, what does "le" mean here?
I vaguely can see this is a unsigned 16bit int?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: le means hear 'little endian' which says byte order of data in memory.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

i found that ([source](http://bruceblinn.com/linuxinfo/ByteOrder.html)) and [that](http://www.gelato.unsw.edu.au/IA64wiki/SparseAnnotations)

Type Identifiers

The following type identifiers correspond to the u16, u32, and u64 types, except they are defined with the bitwise attribute, which is used to restrict their use as integers. The bitwise attribute is used by the sparse utility to make sure the variable is converted to the local processor type before other (unsafe) operations are performed on the variable.

The following types can be used for endian dependent variables after including the linux/kernel.h header file.

```
__le16
__le32  
__le64


__be16
__be32
__be64
```

Comment: Link to sources in kernel code https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/uapi/linux/types.h

Answer (score 4):

Short answer: It stands for [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Long answer: See the links in @Pben's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9680463/180174)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Documentation/sparse.txt](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/sparse.txt?v=4.8):

> And with gcc, all the __bitwise/__force stuff goes away, and it all
>   ends up looking just like integers to gcc.

So my understanding is:

a. It's only used for type checking.

b. If you have

```
typedef __u16 __bitwise __my_type1;
typedef __u16 __bitwise __my_type2;
```

Sparse will give warning if you assign __my_type1 to __my_type2.

c. __bitwise just means order sensitive, it doesn't specify big-endian or little-endian.

Am I right?