# is __le32 and uint32_t types are same

Tags: c

On this page [what does "typedef __u16 __bitwise __le16;" mean in Linux kernel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9680399/what-does-typedef-u16-bitwise-le16-mean-in-linux-kernel)

it says

```
  The following type identifiers correspond to the u16, u32, and u64 types,
  except they are defined with the bitwise attribute, which is used to restrict
  their use as integers
```

And on this page it says [http://www.science.smith.edu/~nhowe/262/oldlabs/ext2.html#:~:text=The%20superblock%20is%20defined%20in,structure%20is%20explained%20in%20ext2_fs](http://www.science.smith.edu/%7Enhowe/262/oldlabs/ext2.html#:%7E:text=The%20superblock%20is%20defined%20in,structure%20is%20explained%20in%20ext2_fs)

```
    The __u32, __u16 and __u8 data types denote unsigned 32-, 16- and 8-bit integer numbers.
```

So can I assume if I have a struct in kernel

```
ext2_super_block {
    uint32_t    s_inodes_count;     /* Inodes count */
    __le32  s_blocks_count;     /* Blocks count */
    __le32  s_r_blocks_count;   /* Reserved blocks count */
    __le32  s_free_blocks_count;    /* Free blocks count */
```

the above can be represented as

```
struct ext2_super_block {
     uint32_t   s_inodes_count;     /* Inodes count */
    uint32_t    s_blocks_count;     /* Blocks count */
    ...
    uint32_t    s_free_blocks_count;    /* Free blocks count */
```

Can the above two structures be same for example if I want `ext2_super_block` in Userspace I can use the later version of `ext2_super_block`

Can any one please do tell in C

Comment: The `le` part could probably mean "**L**ittle **E**ndian". So the type-name also infer semantics.

Comment: And why don't you search for the definition of `__le32` and see what's said there?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for comment .  its defined as `typedef __u16 __bitwise __le16;` what is `__bitwise.` whats alternative to it in userspace.

Comment: `bitwise` is defined as `__attribute__((bitwise))` and, as far as I can tell, is only used by [Sparse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse) for static analysis in the Linux kernel.

Comment: @Codo I am on intel x86-64 so do I not need to use it?

Comment: @user786 it has nothing to do with x86-64. You use it when you need a type that's always little endian regardless of platform. Who knows what are you using it for so we can't answer that

Comment: @phuclv filesystem struct super block

Comment: an on-disk structure needs to be the same in all platforms, even big-endian ones so obviously an endian attribute like that must be used